# 301 Redirect with Domain Alias

Tags: redirects

Hi and thanks in advance for any help!

Our main domain is ecologyproject.org, which contains information for all of our program sites.

We have purchased other domain names, specific to our program sites, e.g. epibelize.org

DNS for both domain names point to the same IP, so they currently pull the same exact content. So essentially epibelize.org is a domain alias.

So currently, epibelize.org will just pull up our main page/site. We would like to have epibelize.org pull a subset of pages though; so if someone navigates to epibelize.org via browser URL, we would like that to pull up ecologyproject.org/programs/local-communities-campuses/belize.

Currently: epibelize.org -> ecologyproject.org
Desired: epibelize.org -> ecologyproject.org/programs/local-communities-campuses/belize

Can we do this? Or hosting provider said to do a 301 redirect, and I have tried this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

EE v2.10.1 - Detour Pro

Any ideas?

Thanks again!

Derek

Answer (score 1):

Detour Pro won't do this for you, since it doesn't look at root domains, only the parts that come after them.

You can do this via .htaccess though:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^epibelize\.org|www\.epibelize\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ecologyproject.org/programs/local-communities-campuses/belize$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Derek, thank you so much for your answer. I'm pretty clueless when it comes to this, but I do know what an .htaccess file is. I opened ours, and there are already a few rewrites in there. I carefully played around with it, and added your code to the beginning (nothing happened), and alternatively adding it to the end (Internal Server Error 500).

Comment: Is it ok to post our .htaccess file and would you be willing to take a look at it and let me know what I am doing wrong? TIA! -Derek

Comment: I'm no .htaccess expert honestly - though I did just find an error in what I posted (fixed now). Try again? And try putting it last in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Still no re-direct love. I put it first and then last. I keeps just pulling up our main page.